# How do you handle server side validation in Express and Node?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I have a web app which sends my Express server MongoDB ObjectIDs in POST requests. I then use these ObjectIDs to select documents from my database using Mongoose.

I am currently handling errors by grabbing the error from Mongoose's callback, returning from the route handler function and then calling a generic error function which responds with the status and error.

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.send({
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

I am curious as to whether it is good practice to use something like Validate.js to check that the ObjectID is valid before feeding it to Mongoose or simply allowing Mongoose see that it's not valid and allowing it to callback an an error which I then handle with my generic error handler?

I'd be curious to hear an explanation either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

> Mongoose has several built in validators.
>
> ```
> All SchemaTypes have the built in required validator.
> Numbers have min and max validators.
> Strings have enum and match validators.
> ```

For example,

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     myField:  {type String, match:'/\.html$/'}
     myNumField: {type Num,  max:5}
});
```

I imagine you should use their methods since this is what its made for.